# Convert unsigned long to char *

Tags: c

So I have this function:

```
static void doPrint (const char *s)
{
    write (STDOUT_FILENO, s, strlen(s));
}
```

I am trying to pass it an unsigned long variable but nothing I have tried has worked so far. My question is, how do I go about doing this? I was thinking of using something along the lines of _ultoa_s or another similar function.

Any ideas? Thanks

Note: Access to printf, sprintf, ect is restricted

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing the pointer to long variable and the size to your `doPrint` function as below

```
doPrint((char *)(&someLongVariable), sizeof(someLongvariable));

void doPrint(char *inpString, int size)
{
     write (STDOUT_FILENO, inpString, size);
}
```

Comment: See my answer for why I have down voted this:  the OP needs guidance on the big picture, not necessarily being strung along down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly you do not want to pass a `double` to this function.  It expects text to output which is the convention of `stdout`.

Almost certainly, you first need to represent the double's value in characters and pass that to the function.  This is a complex topic, and probably the point of the exercise.  Google for ["convert float to ascii"](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=les;&gs_rn=3&gs_ri=psy-ab&gs_mss=convert%20float%20to%20as&tok=o7gLcbJq5nSIhWArpUyxPQ&cp=21&gs_id=bu&xhr=t&q=convert+float+to+ascii&es_nrs=true&pf=p&safe=off&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=convert+float+to+asii&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42452523,d.cGE&fp=a04951e09a4959a8&biw=1280&bih=674) for some ideas of what you have to do.

---

Follow up:

If you are permitted to use `_ultoa_s`, then certainly you could call [`fcvt()` or `ecvt()`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_fcvt.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention whether "restricted" means that the easy functions (printf and friends) aren't available on your (embedded?) platform, or that this is a restriction of the assignment.

Anyways, what you are doing won't work, ever.  You're passing in a binary variable (a long), it won't automagically get converted to a string.

Check out this function, found [here](http://code.google.com/p/my-itoa/), a compact itoa function.  Some tweaking required to make an ltoa out of it, but it's easy to see how it works.

```
//return the length of result string. support only 10 radix for easy use and better performance
int my_itoa(int val, char* buf)
{
    const unsigned int radix = 10;

    char* p;
    unsigned int a;        //every digit
    int len;
    char* b;            //start of the digit char
    char temp;
    unsigned int u;

    p = buf;

    if (val < 0)
    {
        *p++ = '-';
        val = 0 - val;
    }
    u = (unsigned int)val;

    b = p;

    do
    {
        a = u % radix;
        u /= radix;

        *p++ = a + '0';

    } while (u > 0);

    len = (int)(p - buf);

    *p-- = 0;

    //swap
    do
    {
        temp = *p;
        *p = *b;
        *b = temp;
        --p;
        ++b;

    } while (b < p);

    return len;
}
```